# Text inputs in product options do not show emojis in the orders created, it just shows "???" instead of the emoji, How can I fix this?

Tags: opencart

I am using opencart  2.0.1.1, when customers input text in text and text area product options, the emojis are lost when it creates the orders. The website encoding in general works well with special characters. So I think when order is saved into DB it is losing the encoding needed for emoji to show. Not sure. Anybody have ideas of how I can solve this?

Comment: You could try making it UTF-8

Comment: it is already UTF-8 but for the product option it does not seem to keep the emojis inputted.

Comment: @PaulFeakins any other idea. Im still stuck wtit this. Thanks